# Prove $|\det A| \leq \prod_{j=1}^n ||a_j||$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

Let's say A is a square n by n matrix. ||$x$||=$x^T x$ and x is a real  n-column norm.    How would you show this?  I tried to use the QR factorization here in showing that ||$a_j$||=||$r_j$||, but I'm not sure how far that will get you.

Comment: Gershgorin theorem?

Comment: how would that work?

Comment: Do you mean to prove Hadamard's inequality? $|\det(A)|^2 \le \prod_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} |a_{jk}|^{2}$

Comment: Something's wrong $$\det(2\cdot I) = 2^n > n\cdot 2^2 = \sum_j \|a_j\|$$ for large $n$ (perhaps product instead of sum?).

Answer (score 5):

Let $A=QR$ be the QR factorisation of $A$ with $R=[r_1,\ldots,r_n]$. Then Mr Hadamard says that
$$
\left|\,\det A\,\right|
=
\left|\,\det QR\,\right|
=
\left|\,\det Q\,\right|\;\left|\,\det R\,\right|
=
\left|\,\det R\,\right|
=
\prod_{i=1}^n\left|\,r_{ii}\,\right|
\leq
\prod_{i=1}^n\|r_i\|=\prod_{i=1}^n\|a_i\|.
$$

Comment: Can you explain why the norms of the column vectors of R and A are the same?

Comment: Because $a_i^Ta_i=(Qr_i)^T(Qr_i)=r_i^T(Q^TQ)r_i=r_i^Tr_i$.

Comment: gotcha, should have thought of that.

Comment: I am curious. When you say "Mr Hadamard says that", did you mean that he used this particular proof for the inequality?

Comment: @dineshdileep No.